# How to get duplicate elements from in a nested List

Tags: python, list

I've made a nested list like this, l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Now, I want to print all the 1's or 2's from each nested lists into another list r[].

For example r should be, r = [2, 2, 2] or [1, 1, 1]

I've tried follwing,

```
for i in l:
    if(i == 0):
        r.append(i)
        print(r)
```

But, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: In `if(i == 0):` `i` is a _list_, it can never be equal to zero.

Comment: Change to ``if i == 1``, move print outside of for loop.

Comment: Do you have to just check for 1 and 2? How about 3 which is also duplicated in the example?

Comment: @ForceBru Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in l:
    for j in i:
        if(j == 1):
            r.append(j)
print(r)
```

output:

```
[1,1,1]
```

Here i is a sub list in the list l and j is an item in sub list i. So if j is equal to 1 it will get appended to the list r.